# How do I use sys.exit(0) in an arcpy script to exit early without having an error message show up?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I have an arcpy tool script for ArcGIS 10.0 that has two major functional sections.  The user can choose whether or not to run the second section.  If the user chooses NOT to run the second section, I simply want to run a cleanup function and exit the script with a sys.exit(0) **without having an error message posted to the tool results window.**  There are two major threads here in GIS-SE about exiting arcpy scripts, but the solutions therein don't specifically address the error message.  The general structure of the code is as follows:

```
import sys
##import arcpy

def CleanUp():
    print 'Cleaning up ...\n'

def finish():
    CleanUp()
    print 'Exiting ...'
    sys.exit(0)

do_more = False  #or True ... input from user

#Section 1:  do some stuff
print 'Doing some stuff ...\n'

if not do_more:
    finish()

#Section 2:  do more stuff
print 'doing more stuff ...'
CleanUp()
```

If I run this code in the Python interpreter outside of ArcGIS/arcpy, it works as I'd expect, exiting gracefully with no error message; however, in my arcpy script with this same structure, the script exits, but a SystemExit error message is posted to the tool results window.  Is there a way to make the arcpy tool script eat the exception and bury the SystemExit error message?

Comment: Just taking a wild stab here, but is it possible that you could "del arcpy" before calling the SystemExit in your script?

Comment: @Dan - I doubt it, but it's an interesting idea ... hmmm ... what the heck.  I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: thank you for posting concise code example which clearly illustrates the logic and leaves out the extras. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: fixed in 10.1. For now, you're going to need to add an extra level of indentation. This might encourage some useful refactoring to your code though. Any time you get a large number of lines in a single script/routine, you'll want to think about cutting it up into smaller sections (functions, classes) anyway.

```
def main():
    <your code>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except SystemExit as err:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  Yes, I should bite the bullet and refactor.  It's just hard to do that with the client breathing down my neck. Such is life.

Answer (score 3):

ArcPy [messes with your Python environment](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3672).  In short, either don't do sys.exit() or find/call arcpy's "cleanup-before-exit" (if one exists) function before calling sys.exit().

Comment: The way that Python's executable handles `sys.exit()` is a sort of dirty trick -- calling `exit` raises a `SystemExit` exception and the top-level interpreter, which normally prints a traceback, will detect the exception type and terminate the interpreter. Embedding a Python interpreter in another application, such as the ArcGIS family of executables, requires a nontrivial amount of implementation-specific code such as this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to 'bury' the SystemExit error message, but you could always restructure your code to avoid calling sys.exit

```
import sys
##import arcpy

def DoMoreStuff():
    print 'doing more stuff ...'

def CleanUp():
    print 'Cleaning up ...'

def finish():
    CleanUp()
    print 'Exiting ...'

do_more = False  #or True ... input from user

#Section 1:  do some stuff
print 'Doing some stuff ...'

if do_more:DoMoreStuff()

finish()
```

Comment: True, but the two sections in my arcpy script are rather huge.  I would rather not create yet another level of indentation and have to deal with the scoping issues that would ensue ... but, yes, this would be a solution.  What's really frustrating is that the error message appears only when you use sys.exit in arcpy.  Out in regular Python the message isn't posted, because the SystemExit exception isn't considered an error.