# How to programmatically close a QMessagebox without clicking ok or X?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

So part of my script in PyQGIS is this:

```
QMessageBox.warning(None,"Warning","bla bla bla")
```

The box apperas just fine but i want it to close after a few seconds so i am looking for something like this:

```
QMessageBox.warning(None,"Warning","bla bla bla")
time.sleep(2)
(command that closes the box without clicking ok or hitting X)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nathan W is correct. But, if you still want to display a QMessageBox with autoclose behaviour. You can do it bu subclassing the QMessageBox like this:

```
class CustomMessageBox(QMessageBox):

def __init__(self, *__args):
    QMessageBox.__init__(self)
    self.timeout = 0
    self.autoclose = False
    self.currentTime = 0

def showEvent(self, QShowEvent):
    self.currentTime = 0
    if self.autoclose:
        self.startTimer(1000)

def timerEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.currentTime += 1
    if self.currentTime >= self.timeout:
        self.done(0)

@staticmethod
def showWithTimeout(timeoutSeconds, message, title, icon=QMessageBox.Information, buttons=QMessageBox.Ok):
    w = CustomMessageBox()
    w.autoclose = True
    w.timeout = timeoutSeconds
    w.setText(message)
    w.setWindowTitle(title)
    w.setIcon(icon)
    w.setStandardButtons(buttons)
    w.exec_()
```

And call it like this:

```
CustomMessageBox.showWithTimeout(3, "Auto close in 3 seconds", "QMessageBox with autoclose", icon=QMessageBox.Warning)
```

This code is an adaptation from [this answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236800/auto-close-qmessagebox).

Comment: But don't, because that is mean to your users.

Comment: @NathanW  the only user of this is me and my professor so no worries! Thanks for the answers they really helped. I got another question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137537/how-to-stop-a-pyqgis-script-that-has-an-infinite-loop-using-the-keyboard Go to my last comment to save some time

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a message box for this. It is not what they are for and will make people cry.  Use the message bar.

```
iface.messageBar().pushWarning("title", "message")
```

or

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("title", "message")
```

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMessageBar.html

Comment: @Stelios what is your version? an alternative is to avoid the shortcut e.g. iface.messageBar().pushMessage("title", "message", QgsMessageBar.WARNING) and study this class: http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMessageBar.html